# Calculating Throughput, Goodput, end-to-end delay time, Packets lost count from scalar file generated by the Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

In a network with some wireless nodes, after simulation, the Omnet++ generates a scalar file.
I want to calculate throughput, goodput, end-to-end delay time, packets lost count from the generated scalar file.
Is there a tools that calculate them? or script?
If there isn't, what is the best solution?
I search similar question in the stackoverflow site, most questions are unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using INET, if the application layer emits a `packetReceived` signal then you can use the `dataAge(packetReceived)` and `throughput(packetReceived)` result filters.

This will produce these results in the `.sca` and `.vec` files.

For an example of how to use them see: https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/007bc454ec7749e2dea8fcb808429d21074880ad/src/inet/applications/udpapp/UdpSink.ned

Some example applications which will work with this are: IpvxTrafGen, SctpClient/Peer, TcpAppBase (and derivatives), UdpBasicApp/Burst, UdpSink etc.